# jquery - Deferring execution of a function until after other events have occurred

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a couple of ajax requests that grab some data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/bin/MVC/Reporting/GetReportTemplates',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        reportingMetaData.ReportTemplates = data.Data;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: '/bin/MVC/Reporting/GetReportTopTypes',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        reportingMetaData.ReportTopTypes = data.Data;
    }
}
```

AFTER BOTH of these have returned, I want to run another function.

I'm aware of jquery deferred, but I have never used it, and am unsure how to apply it in this instance.

Could anyone assist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var a1 = $.ajax({
    url: '/bin/MVC/Reporting/GetReportTemplates',
    type: "GET"
});
var a2 = $.ajax({
    url: '/bin/MVC/Reporting/GetReportTopTypes',
    type: "GET"
});
$.when(a1, a2).then(function() {
    //Both ajax requests have completed successfully
});
```

Comment: Ah cool - I had tried using function a1(){...} function as(){...} $.when(a1,a2).then(function(){}); but that didn't work - Many thanks

Comment: @BonyT that would work if the functions `return $.ajax` and you did `(a1(), a2()).then`. It's the return value of `$.ajax` (a promise object) that you need to pass to `$.when`

Comment: Ah  - makes sense now :) Many thanks, modifying code as you suggested works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You need `$.when()`.

```
var req_1 = $.ajax({...});
var req_2 = $.ajax({...});
$.when(req_1, req_2).done(function(response_1, response_2) {
    //do something here when both requests done
});
```

It's also worth pointing out that `$.when()` can take deferred OR NON-deferred objects as arguments. This means it can act in cases where the request may be synchronous OR asynchronous. If you happen to be in the UK, an upcoming article in .NET magazine by me looks at this in more detail.

Comment: Thanks +1 for the answer, Esailija just pipped you though so I'll "accept" his answer.

Comment: Yeah that's fair enough. I'll beat him next time :)